# JUnit functional tests for GUI elements: suppress dialogs from opening

Tags: java, junit, functional-testing

I would like to run a test which is not a unit test and not a full GUI integration test.

The class which is to be tested shows dynamic UI content. My Problem is, that in some situtations an informative popup window is opened.

Is there any way to suppress dialogs from opening for `JUnit` tests? Using a programmatic approach like a boolean within the class is probably quite confusing to other developers?!

Comment: I'm not too familiar with UI development, but isn't this what *mocking frameworks* are for?

Comment: If the code that actually displays the popup is wrapped in a utility class, you can use the real one in your app and the mock in your test.  That allows you to handle the problem you describe and test that the correct popup is displayed.

Comment: Insert a layer (i.e. Facade) between the UI parts that shall be tested and the UI parts that represent the user interactions, then mock these UI parts and make them behave as the user would for your test.

Comment: This is a good example of why GUI design patterns, such as MVC or MVP (my favourite) are so useful.